# Java convert list of int[] to array of int[] - concurrent safe

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, list

I have a `List<int[]>` and I would like to convert it to an `int[][]`

I have tried like this:

```
      private List<int[]> pos = new LinkedList<>();
      ...
      public int[][] getPos() {
        int[][] ret = new int[pos.size()][2];
        int i = 0;
        for (Object o : pos) {
          ret[i] = Arrays.stream((int[]) o).toArray();
          i++;
        }
        return ret;
      }
```

The big problem in my case is that an other thread is changing the List during the process of convertion. So I get a `ConcurrentModificationException` on my foreach.

Is there any other ways of doing this like with Streams ? That would be concurent safe.

Regards

Comment: Make a local copy of the list beforehand, that is the way to go with threads.

Comment: Consider synchronization or locks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to use a ConcurrentQueue. This was you can be adding values while you are consuming them. Note: you won't be able to copy any `int[]` produced after you have done the copy.

Comment: Worked like a charm for a quick fix. But I'll look further on locks/synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

`LinkedList` is not threadsafe so it is not possible to make your program thread safe without using locks/synchronization.

But if you change it to e.g. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` it would be easier, you could iterate over it safely while other thread will write to it (but you will copy only the list state that was when you started foreach/iterator, all changes to the `List` won't be reflected until you do another foreach/iterator).